# Interpretation of $\mathcal H^k$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

For a holomorphic family $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ between complex manifolds, the map $\pi$ is a proper holomorphic submersion, $X_t:=\pi^{-1}(t)$, $t\in B$, $X=X_0$, we have the isomorphism $H^k(X,\mathbb C)\cong H^k(X_t,\mathbb C)$, then I want to understand the vector bundle structure of $\mathcal H^k:=R^k\pi_*\mathbb C\otimes \mathcal O_B$ (see Voisin's book *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry, I*. p.228-231 for definitions).

For a smooth form $\omega\in A^k(\mathcal X)$ such that $\omega|_{X_t}\in Z^k(X_t)$, which means the restriction of $\omega$ to $X_t$ is a closed $k$ form on $X_t$, let $\mathcal Z^k$ denote the Abelian group formed by such kind of $\omega$. Similarly, if $\omega$ satisfies $\omega|_{X_t}\in B^k(X_t)$, the Abelian group formed by such kind of $k$-forms is denoted by $\mathcal B^k$. Then can we interpret $\mathcal H^k$ as $\frac{\mathcal Z^k}{\mathcal B^k}$?